# Does redis itself have cache?

Tags: caching, hash, redis

What's the difference between query for a specific key once and many times? does it cost the same time every time, or 2nd will be faster than 1st? Hope someone can give a hand:) I've checked the official site and found nothing on this.

Comment: Ignore Spatial locality, the answer is NO. Redis doesn't take the initiative to cache data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis is an in-memory database, which means all data it manages is stored in RAM. That being the case, there is no need/way for Redis to cache the data and every request is served in constant and predictable latency.